# how to ensure puppet exec run on every event triggered?

Tags: puppet

I want puppet exec to run on first deployment of a file and on every further change on the file. For that I have created below code in puppet .

Exec does not run on first file deployment. I am assuming it is because of refreshonly. Does anyone know what needs to be changed in the code?

```
define dev_tools::javacert(
  $keystore="/etc/alternatives/java_sdk/jre/lib/security/cacerts",
  $storepass='xxx',
  $alias = $name,
  $filecertpath = "/var/lib/certs/${name}.crt",

){
  file{
    $filecertpath:
      source => "puppet:///modules/${module_name}/sonarqube/${::env}/${::server_location}/${filecertpath}",
      mode   => '0644',
      notify => Exec["deploy_javacert_${name}"];
  }
  exec {
    "deploy_javacert_${name}":
       path => "/usr/bin",
       command => "keytool -importcert -keystore ${keystore} -alias $alias -file $filecertpath -storepass ${storepass} -noprompt  2>/dev/null",
       provider => shell,
       refreshonly => true;
  }

}
```

Comment: As @AlexHarvey mentions in his answer, your code does not match the behavior you are describing and should work as desired. Could you provide logs and output proving otherwise?

Comment: If the `Exec` is not running and no error is reported then the most likely scenarios are that (1) no `dev_tools::javacert` resource is being applied in the first place, or (2) the file being managed already exists, with the mode and contents specified for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of refreshonly looks correct. I am unable to reproduce this. Using this simplified version of your code:

**Attempt to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):**

```puppet
# test.pp

file { 'foo': 
  path   => '/tmp/foo',
  source => '/tmp/source',
  notify => Exec['bar'],
}
exec { 'bar':
  path        => '/bin',
  command     => 'echo "baz qux"',
  refreshonly => true,
  logoutput   => true,
}
```

**Setup:**

```
▶ touch /tmp/source
```

**Initial run:**

```
▶ puppet apply test.pp
...
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[foo]/content: content changed '{md5}0a227d644d5435d49addae1da06e909c' to '{md5}d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[bar]/returns: baz qux
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[bar]: Triggered 'refresh' from 1 event
```

**Subsequent run:**

```
▶ puppet apply test.pp
...
Notice: Compiled catalog for 192-168-1-2.tpgi.com.au in environment production in 0.08 seconds
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.03 seconds
```

**New content:**

```
▶ echo foobar > /tmp/source
▶ puppet apply test.pp
...
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[foo]/content: content changed '{md5}d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e' to '{md5}14758f1afd44c09b7992073ccf00b43d'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[bar]/returns: baz qux
```

Comment: Yes it worked now. I dont know why it was not working earlier.

Comment: @devops glad it’s sorted anyway